# Queueing HTTP, emails, and TCP messages in Python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, django-celery

I have a system that sends different types of messages (HTTP, SMTP, POP, IMAP, and regular TCP) to different systems, and I need to queue all of those messages in my system, in case of other systems in-availability.

I'm a bit new to the message queueing concept. so I don't know the best python library that I shall go for.

Is Django-celery (and the underling components - RabbitMQ, MySql, django, apache) is the best choice for me? Will this library cover all my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Pika client or the Kombu client.  Celery is a whole framework for job queues, which you may not need - but it's worth taking a look if you want to understand a queue use case.

Comment: I want to queue messages (mail, http, and tcp) to other systems I don't control...will kombu will help me on that?